# What is a chopin chain?

Tags: jewelry, chain-mail

I'm trying to select a chain for a pendant, and one of the options is "chopin" chain, vs a "rope" chain (which looks the same to me).

What's the difference, where does this style of chain come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The chopin chain is a type of rope chain in which every slightly twisted link embraces two others**:

[image: chopin chain]
<sup>([source](https://www.gearbest.com/necklaces-pendants/pp_009278066953.html). click to enlarge)</sup>

Depending on the thickness of the links, the character of the chain can seem a lot fuller:

[image: chopin chain]
<sup>([source](https://www.dhgate.com/product/diy-jewelry-chopin-necklace-4-5-6mm-keel/421621270.html). click to enlarge)</sup>

---

If google images is any indication, the most common type of **rope chain**, for comparison is the one that, not surprisingly, has the spiralling character of a regular rope:

[image: rope chain]
<sup>([source](https://www.thegldshop.com/products/rope-chain-4mm). click to enlarge)</sup>

**In the rope chain, every straight link embraces four others.**
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHfE6UaORO4) is a video demonstrating the making of such a chain.

Comment: I couldn't find the actual definition, so kudos.  Just to add: appearance-wise, rope has a spiral look, while chopin has a more uniform braided look.  The style is often called "wheat" or "foxtail".

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. I do believe both foxtail and wheat have different looks. Foxtail at least has a decidedly symmetrical appearance. Wheat could indeed be that second variant of chopin, with the broader links.